# how to add css for div tag

Tags: html, css

I want to display the div tag from top of 'rest' div tag.
'Rest' div tag is like container. I want to display the menu on left side and want to display the 'heading' div tag on the margin-top of the rest tag.

In my layout I drawn 'menu' div in green color which is correct.I want to display the div tag 'heading' on the position where I marked in red box.But my problem is now it is displayed in the botton which i drawn it in blue colored box.

[image: layout]

```css
.heading{
 float:left;
 margin-top:0px;
 margin-left:170px;
 height:25px;
 width:79%;
 background-color:#15317E;
 
}
.rest {
  height: 685px;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #e5e3e3 5%, #ffffff 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #e5e3e3), color-stop(1, #ffffff));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #e5e3e3 5%, #ffffff 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#e5e3e3", endColorstr="#ffffff");
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e5e3e3, ffffff);
  background-color: #e5e3e3;
  border: 1px solid #f9f2f2;
  border-width: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0px 7px;
}
.sidemenu {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 150px;
 
  height: 250px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #f9f2f2;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.content {
  border-left: thick solid #f9f2f2;
}
hr {
  margin: 0;
  margin-left:170px;
  width: 1px; 
  height: 660px;
 border:0;
background: #fff;
}
.menu{
  height: 45px;
  width: 150px;
  text-align:left;
  margin-left:2px;
  
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #e5e3e3 5%, #ffffff 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #e5e3e3), color-stop(1, #ffffff));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #e5e3e3 5%, #ffffff 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#e5e3e3", endColorstr="#ffffff");
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e5e3e3, ffffff);
  background-color: #e5e3e3;
  border: 1px solid #f9f2f2;
  border-width: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0px 7px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="rest">
                  <div class="side">
                   <div class="sidemenu">
                        <div class="1 menu">
                          <a href="admin_dashboard.php" class="astext">Profile</a>
                        </div> <!--End of menu1 -->
                        <div class="2 menu">
                          <a href="clients.php" class="astext">Clients</a>
                        </div> <!--End of menu 2-->
                        <div class="3 menu">
                          <a href="employees.php" class="astext">Employees</a>
                        </div> <!--End of menu 3-->
                        <div class="menu 4">
                        <a href="admin_file_view.php" class="astext">Documents</a>
                        </div> <!--End of menu 4-->
                   </div> <!--End of side menu -->
                   </div>  <!--End of side div -->
                   <hr>
                      <div class="heading" >
                         
                      </div>   <!-- End of heading div -->
                   <div class="content">
                     
                   </div> <!--End of content -->
                </div> <!--End of rest div -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your .heading, hr and add new css .side class. I think that it will be solved.

```
.heading{
      float: left;
      margin-top: 0px;
      margin-left: 0px;
      height: 25px;
      width: 66%;
      background-color: #15317E;

    }
    .side{
      width: 33%;
      float: left;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    hr {
      margin: 0;
      width: 1px;
      height: 660px;
      border: 0;
      background: #fff;
      float: left;
    }
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gthpvtxc/)

Comment: This is not width is not fact, rest div will be 100% base and left div plus right div equal and hr equal 100%. Please vote me.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding CSS class to `.side` and update `.header`

```
.heading{
 float:left;
 height:25px;
 width:79%;
 background-color:#15317E;
}
.rest {
  height: 685px;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #e5e3e3 5%, #ffffff 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #e5e3e3), color-stop(1, #ffffff));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #e5e3e3 5%, #ffffff 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#e5e3e3", endColorstr="#ffffff");
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e5e3e3, ffffff);
  background-color: #e5e3e3;
  border: 1px solid #f9f2f2;
  border-width: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0px 7px;
}
.sidemenu {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 150px;

  height: 250px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #f9f2f2;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.content {
  border-left: thick solid #f9f2f2;
}
hr {
  margin: 0;
  margin-left:170px;
  width: 1px; 
  height: 660px;
 border:0;
background: #fff;
}
.menu{
  height: 45px;
  width: 150px;
  text-align:left;
  margin-left:2px;

  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #e5e3e3 5%, #ffffff 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #e5e3e3), color-stop(1, #ffffff));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #e5e3e3 5%, #ffffff 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#e5e3e3", endColorstr="#ffffff");
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e5e3e3, ffffff);
  background-color: #e5e3e3;
  border: 1px solid #f9f2f2;
  border-width: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0px 7px;
}
.side{
    float:left; width:19%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add these two css properties to your ".heading" in your css part

```
.heading{  
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
}
```